# Is that possible to use Torque.js outside cartoDB?

Tags: mysql, data-visualization, cartodb

I am currently working on a project which allows user to play back the movement of school buses.

We already got part of the data visualized using Torque.js. Torque gets the data from cartoDB Database via username and table name.

My question is, is that possible to make Torque get the data directly from a local database rather than cartoDB Database?

Our data is about 11 GB. A enterprise plan is required to upload all the data. We were still trying to figure out if there's a way to get around that.

If that is not possible or take too much effort, another way we were thinking is to set up a server, which takes in a date. The server then query the local database to get all data from that particular day and upload only that portion of data to cartoDB database for torque to use. But we were kinda worried about the performance.

Or is there any other recommended data visualization library?

Any help or suggestion would be highly appreciated!